# Alternative to imageNamed

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage

In iOS, using Objective-C, I'm trying to give to a composer an image. I pick that image from gallery or camera, and I called it:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

So, now I should set it to my composer, but imageNamed doesn't work by using this code

```
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"imagename"];
```

is there any alternative to set my image to that composer?

I said that I pick that image from gallery or camera, so it is stored locally 
picked from here:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;    
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

stored in this way:

```
 _image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 self.imageView.image = _image;
```

Comment: Where is the image stored? `imageNamed:` only works with images in your app's resource bundle.

Comment: Update your question, don't put code in comments.

Comment: Since your image is stored in the property named `image`, you just need to use that: `[composer setImage:self.image];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are storing the image obtained from `UIImagePickerController` in

```
self.imageView.image
```

Then you set the image using

```
[composer setImage:self.imageView.image]
```

But if it is stored in

```
self.image
```

Then you have to use

```
[composer setImage:self.image]
```